# How to merge two PCollection KV<> by key?

Tags: java, apache-beam

Im trying to ouput a SUM and a COUNT for the same key.
Eg. Given a .csv with millions of events of plane delays. 
Using Apache Beam (Java) I want to SUM the durations of the delays for each plane, and COUNT how many delays each plane had.

each row has `plane_id, delay_duration, date`, etc.

Im trying to create two PCollections and want to kind of merge them before output.

```
PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> sum =  eventInfo.apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(),TypeDescriptors.integers())).via((Event.EventInfo gInfo) -> KV.of(gInfo.getKey('plane_id'), gInfo.getDuration()))).apply(Sum.integersPerKey());

PCollection<KV<String, Long>> count =  eventInfo.apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptors.integers())).via((Event.EventInfo gInfo) -> KV.of(gInfo.getKey('plane_id'), gInfo.getDuration()))).apply(Count.perKey());
```

This two PCollections work as expected, but I can't figure it out how to output it (merge it?) in 3 columns key | sum | count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need [CoGBK](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey.java), which will help you co-locate your sum and count for the same key.

Comment: After a few hours of searching, I've created 2 tupples, and used CoGroupByKey, as you said. Then, I've manage to output it by creating a class with the desired output

Comment: `Event.MyResult xpto = new Event.MyResult(id, sum, count);`
`c.output(xpto);`